# Using browser.restart() in Protractor

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to restart my browser in the `beforeAll()` section of my Protractor spec (using jasmine2).   This appears to be working, and each of my `it()`'s seem to technically function as well, but each `it()` is failing with:

`Failed: browser.restart is not a function`

My understanding is that beforeAll() executes once prior to any `it()` blocks, so I'm not sure why this failure repeats throughout the test.  Nor do I understand the error as this appears to be a valid function:

https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.restart

Any ideas why this is?

Here is the relevant code:

```
describe('The App', function () {

  beforeAll(function () {
    // Clean up any artifacts that may have been left by failing tests
    loginPage.navigate()
    loginPage.login(user, pass)
    mainPage.resetApps([existingAppName])
    mainPage.logout()
    browser.restart()
  })

  it('should do stuff', function () {
    ...
  }
})
```

Comment: What protractor version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Version 2.3.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`browser.restart()` [was introduced in Protractor 3.0.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3.0.0/CHANGELOG.md#features). You need to upgrade.